# UICollectionView top cell from zIndex not selected with overlapping cells

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, z-index

I have a `UICollectionView` with a number of cells that overlap each other.

I set their `zIndex` in a `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass with `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` so they appear in the desired order visually.
The hit areas for touch evens work as expected with the cells with a higher `zIndex` coming though the `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` method when tapping the overlapping areas of the cell.

I transition to a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass and when I transition back to the first `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass the cells with a higher `zIndex` are not always selected when tapping the overlapping areas.

Further investigation revealed that the order of the `UICollectionViewCell`s in the `UICollectionView` subviews is determining which cell is tapped.

I have written a method to reorder the subviews but this seems like a bit of a hack.

Is there a better way for the `UICollectionView` cells to return the expected index path in `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` based on how the cells appear visually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my testing, it seems that layout-to-layout transitions ignore the `zIndex` property of the pushed view controller's layout. This smells like a bug. You can work around the issue by reloading after the view controller appears:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Reloading will clear selection, so we remember which index paths are selected before reload
    NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems;
    NSIndexSet *allSections = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.collectionView.numberOfSections)];

    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

        // First, reload to correct the zOrder
        [self.collectionView reloadSections:allSections];

        // Then, re-select the index paths
        if (selectedIndexPaths.count)
        {
            for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in selectedIndexPaths)
            {
                [self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                                  animated:YES
                                            scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
            }
        }
    } completion:nil];
}
```

It's still a bit of a hack, but less messy than manually reordering the collection view's subviews.

Comment: Awesome! I also added [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]; before and [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES]; in the completion block so the cells wouldn't fade in and out.

Comment: Glad this helped. You could also do `[self.collectionView reloadData]` instead of `reloadSections:` to reload without animations - it's just a little less code :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be the right approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40010956/1032900
Putting reload in viewDidAppear could cause unnecessary reloads